# I can't see the folders I created in my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have been working on a project in C# in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. Since I have a lot of C# files I decided to put them in a few folders based on their type. For example an `interfaces` folder and an `enumerations` folder.

Now when I open my project I can't see any of my folders and all of my C# files are not in folders. I can't open the files because it says that the directory has changed or has been deleted. I am adding a photo so you will be able to see what happened to me.

[image: Error message box]

Comment: There is a project file that has a list of the files in your project. If you move them outside of VS, then the project file will now refer to non-existent files. My advice would be to undo all the moves you did, and then redo those moves/folder creations/etc. from within VS, so that the project file is updated as well.

Comment: If you restructured your folders on disk then your VS solution and project have no idea where you moved them to. If there is a way you can undo it and then do your restructuring inside of VS then you'll be fine. You can't change folders and paths outside of VS since all these are kept in the CSProj file

Answer (score 13):

You should've created the folders and moved the files *inside* the VS Solution explorer, then everything is tracked automatically.

The easiest way to fix this is to enable "Show all files" at the top of the solution explorer, refresh the view to make sure you can see everything

Then right-click the slightly grayed out folders and choose "Include in project"

Once that's done, delete the "Broken" old files.

Comment: @user1919052 please accept the correct and most useful answer to your question.  not only this but also for the other questions you ask previously. don't leave question open if it is already solved

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps to add the files back to the solution

1. From the Project menu toggle on "Show All Files"
2. Now you should see the files/folders in Solution Explorer.
3. Select those you want to include
4. right click and choose "Include in Project"
5. after include all files delete the broken file links

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to click "Refresh" in the solution explorer first. Then you will be able to see hidden files, when clicking "Show all files" and you will be able to "include them in project".

Answer (score 0):

sometimes Visual Studio file tree lacks your latest update to solution explorer
so, the solution is to just right click on your solution and select "Sync Namespaces"